# Rosrun executable not found

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to run a node from rosrun (it works when I manually enter ./program inside build directory). Yet it doesn't work when called by rosrun - it finds the directory by tab completion, but not the executable. How can I help it? I need it to use it in launch files.

```
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/user/ros_ws/catkin_ws/src/ros_programme
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166926/rosrun-executable-not-found/) by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LikeSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/18041/likesmith/) on 2014-05-19**:
did you run the setup script for your catkin workspace?

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-19**:
Yes. The problem lies in the location of the executables. They're in catkin_ws/build/package_name and they should be somewhere in devel/lib I think. I guess it's something with the CMake file inside package source, but no idea what exactly.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-19**:
What is the exact command line of your rosrun? What is that package setup and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-19**:
rosrun ros_programme ros_programme - doesn't work
./ros_programme (build/ros_programme directory) works

I'm not sure what you mean by package setup, I'm a little bit green here. After sourcing many things, this is the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

/home/user/ros_ws/catkin_ws/install/share:/home/omikron/ros_ws/catkin_ws/install/stacks:/home/user/ros_ws/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-19**:
Where is your code and "sourcing many things" would be the package setup. Is the binary in any of the paths in your package path? e.g. .../install

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-19**:
Additionally, the packages I put inside catkin_ws (downloaded from miscellaneous locations) usually allow me to easily use rosrun. This is the CMakeLists.txt of my package (also downloaded, but clearly somehow incomplete)

http://pastebin.com/XNkxU93i

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-19**:
The binary is only in build directory (catkin_ws/build/ros_programme).

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-05-19**:
did you type ($source devel/setup.bash) in your catkin_ws before typing rosrun ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT**

The final solution to this was to make sure to call `catkin_package()` in the CMakeLists.txt, and to make sure to call it before any `add_executable()` or `add_library()` calls.

**Original answer**

Looking at your CMakeLists.txt, you've named your executables `ros_aruco` and `subpose`. The correct way to run them is with:

```
rosrun ros_programme ros_aruco
```

Or

```
rosrun ros_programme subpose
```

The relevant lines in your CMakeLists.txt that set these names are:

```
add_executable(ros_aruco src/ros_aruco.cpp)
add_executable(subpose src/subpose.cpp)
```

I would also expect the final binaries to be generated into devel/lib/ros_aruco rather than build/ros_aruco; are you passing any extra flags to catkin_make that might be changing this behavior?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-19**:
Nah, I've just modified the names for some clarity. The real package name is ros_aruco and I want to call it by running rosrun ros_aruco ros_aruco. So still nothing. ;/

Sorry for confusing things.

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-19**:
No, just "catkin_make".

**Comment by [ai-shwarya](https://answers.ros.org/users/25300/ai-shwarya/) on 2016-10-19**:
catkin_package() did the trick for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran across the same error when trying to rosrun after doing a `catkin_make install`, it turned out I had the install TARGETS set to `CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION` instead of `CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION` (because I had copied that from somewhere else?), and the executables were going into install/bin rather than install/lib/my_package.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cmkayjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/38654/cmkayjc/) on 2019-10-25**:
Thanks! This solved my problem! I mistook adding my executable to the part for library installation. The default RUNTIME DESTINATION for libraries and executable are different.